# how to create a fullscreen website design?

Tags: html, css, fullscreen

What i am trying to achieve is something like this: http://www.svkariburnu.com/, i don't know if for this i should use only % in my css for my values or there is something more to it, what i want to do is to create for example a menu where the width is the same as the window,

i tried already using % for the elements and it worked but how can i know the exact percentage to set the remain values where i want them to be?

i looked and i found people who is using js to achieve this, is that necessary?

This is my code so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="banner"></div>

<div id="menu">

<div id="buttom"></div>
<div id="buttom"></div>
<div id="buttom"></div>
<div id="buttom"></div>
<div id="buttom"></div>


</div>

<div id="iframe"></div>

</div>
```

CSS example:

```
 body{
        background:#f7f7f7 url(../images/pattern.png) repeat top left;
        color:#000;
        font-family:'Georgia', 'Trebuchet MS', serif;
        font-size:12px;
    }

    #wrapper{
        width:100%;
        height:900px;
        margin:auto;
    }

    #banner{
        width:100%;
        height:200px;
        float:left;
        background-color:#333
    }

    menu{
        width:100%;
        height:50px;
        float:left;
    }

    #buttom{
        width:20%;
        height:50px;
        float:left;
        background-color:#063;
    }
```

It worked but now for the iframe i dont know how to set it in the middle i don't want the iframe to be full width i need it to be at 80% having 10% at each side free, and so on, how can i manage that? is there a tutorial for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should try and read a few articles about responsive Websites and Media Queries, it will give you at least some start.

Comment: @drip will do but every time i find an article its only about the importance of responsive website never how to be able to do it, will need to look deeper, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this, and whatever happens there will always be spacing at each side;

```
 #wrapper{
        width:100%;
        height:900px;
        margin:auto;
        padding:0 20px 0 20px;
    }
```

Comment: this will make the wrapper 100% of the window width and it will push it 20px to the right...So there will be spacing only on the left side and the right side will be hidden by 20px.

Comment: yes sorry i have added padding so whatever is in the wrapper will now have a left and right spacing of 20px with the wrapper still taking up 100%

Comment: Nope it will still be the same. It will be taking 100% of the window with + 40px. In order to work like this you should add box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: Well i spose you could just add a border of width like 20px to the wrapper.

Comment: Nope it will be still the same... :) Try them and you will see. That's why the box-sizing property was added, the solution to this headache.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for the  `<div>` elements with id "bottom", use `class="bottom"` instead.

For the `<div id="iframe">`, you can try using `width:80%; margin:auto;` , see if that gives you the desired effect.

Comment: thanks for the advise, but when i changed div id for div class i cant see my menu anymore, sorry i am not used to classes unless it is for texts, i still have menu{widht:100%, height: 50px; float:left;} and then .button{width:20%, height:50px; float:left; background-color:#063} its that the only change i should make or i am doing something wrong?

Comment: yeah that should be okay. It must be something else thats wrong. If you don't mind try creating a jsFiddle and post the link in your question, so that people can help you a lot more easily.

Comment: ah yeah... i found the problem it was a grammar mistake. it's working now ,thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

to get a live visual experience about the width:

- Firefox -> get FireBug -> rightClick -> Inspect Element with FireBug
- Chrome -> RightClick -> InspectElement

now you can select the html element on the left side and get the css part on the right side.
At this point you can click on the n% (for example 100%) and use your up and down keys to change it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your page to be based on the viewport size, you probably want [viewport units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths). Be careful using them though, [they may not be supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) in the browsers you are developing for.

So, if you need an element to have a size that is 80% of the viewport, you can just add `width: 80vw` to your css. Likewise, if you need 10% if the viewport in space on each side, you can add `margin: 0 10vw;`. (Actually, it might be better to let the margins handle themselves with `margin: 0 auto;`)